# Flutter app crashing after updating to Xcode 15

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, xcode15

When I run Flutter code on a physical iOS device via Android Studio it tells me to run via Xcode and when I run via Xcode it crashes. How do I fix it?

[image]

I am using Xcode 15 and iOS 17.0.3.

Comment: Is that working on ios simulator?

Comment: It doesn't work in simulator and real device